# Python version of C++ all_of

Tags: c++, python, built-in

Is there any better way (using built-in functions) to rewrite the following piece of code:

```
def all_of(iterable, predicate):
    for elem in iterable:
        if not predicate(elem):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: If you like to operate on streams, you'll love the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) is a builtin:

```
all(predicate(e) for e in iterable)
```

I don't think it is worth it to define something like this:

```
def all_of(iterable, predicate):
    return all(predicate(e) for e in iterable)
```

Comment: So easy, should have guessed. Thanks!